# With react-router-redux, how should a non-route presentational component get the location?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

Is there a good way to access the location from non-route components, where `MapStateToProp`'s `ownProps` is not populated with the location?  In my case, I need the location a few layers down from the routed component; avoiding lots of hierarchical parameter-passing is part of why we use Redux, so I'm not inclined to just pass the location down from the routed component through all the intervening layers.  I've ended up using the `routing` store directly in `mapStateToProps` (warned against in the docs), as the best of bad choices.

The scenario is one where a set of common "frame" components are laid down by parent route, and they need to change slightly depending on context.

Comment: What part of the docs discouraged this? Basically whenever you need access to store you should have a `container` and pass the store down. You can create a dummy container above your `frame`s and pass down from there instead all the way from top.

Comment: @norbertpy See [this section of the react-router-redux home page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#how-do-i-access-router-state-in-a-container-component).  The recommended approach (using `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps` only works in route components (i.e., those listed in the router configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v3.0.0 of `react-router` you can use [`withRouter`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/pull/3444) to achieve this.
For now, you should update your package.json to point to `3.0.0-alpha.1`.

There's a video from @gaeron: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-withrouter-to-inject-the-params-into-connected-components

Answer (score 0):

Also the workaround is to use a `context` from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) so you could specify it in the needed component directly without passing down as a property